# Flex - status bar while javascript function is running

Tags: javascript, apache-flex, photoshop-script

I am seeking direction on this question. I have a Flex function calling to Javascript that is manipulating files, copying to another directory etc. Depending on the size of the operation, it can take some time to complete.

Is there a way that I can display an animated 'loading' status while that function is running?

Thanks

Comment: Enable the loading screen right after calling the javascript function and when the javascript function finishes its operation do a call back to the flash function in that function disable the loading screen

Comment: @rajesh.adhi Thanks. Could you help me with a sample for this? It makes complete sense, I am just not familiar with enabling loading screen.  Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a "Please Wait" spinner while data is being imported](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226399/how-to-create-a-please-wait-spinner-while-data-is-being-imported)